# Inserting empty string into auto_increment column in MySQL 5

Tags: php, mysql

I've inherited a project which we are trying to migrate to MySQL 5 from MySQL 4.0(!) and from myISAM to InnoDB. Queries are now falling down because they are being constructed using an ADODB connection's ->qstr() on all parameters, including ints. Where no value is provided I end up with:

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('', 'stuff'...)
```

where the first column is an auto_increment. This causes an error (fair enough since '' isn't an int). Is there a switch in MySQL to make it behave as it used to (I assume it just silently converted to 0?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:

I just ran a few tests and what I wrote below won't help you at all. The error is because of the wrong datatype, and the SQL setting I suggested doesn't change that. I'll leave this answer here though, since it might be helpful to someone else.

---

Firstly, double check that the column really is auto increment - a couple of times I've had `CREATE TABLE` files where the fact that a column is auto_increment was sadly missing.

The other thing which might help is to check that [`NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero) is not turned on.

`SET SQL_MODE=''` should turn it off.

Comment: SET SQL_MODE='' seems to do the trick actually, as it turns off 'TRADITIONAL' which causes incorrect data type to be an error rather than a warning

Comment: @QmunkE - well how about that.